# Flutter build to real device get PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter

When I built to simulator it work fine without any problem
but when I switching to build to real device  or  try to build ipa I get this error
PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Trying many answers from many sites when google it but  not working
any one can help me please .